# Place 3D model in place of coordinate

Tags: ios, swift, location, arkit, 3d-modelling

I am working on an AR project using ARKit.
I want to place a 3D model in place of Coordinate. I am able to add Image in place of coordinate below is the code

```
public init(location: CLLocation?, image: UIImage) {
        let plane = SCNPlane(width: image.size.width / 100, height: image.size.height / 100)
        plane.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = image
        plane.firstMaterial!.lightingModel = .constant

        annotationNode = AnnotationNode(view: nil, image: image)
        annotationNode.geometry = plane

        super.init(location: location)

        let billboardConstraint = SCNBillboardConstraint()
        billboardConstraint.freeAxes = SCNBillboardAxis.Y
        constraints = [billboardConstraint]

        addChildNode(annotationNode)
    }
```

Code of AnnotationNode class for placing an image on Coordinate.

```
open class AnnotationNode: SCNNode {
    public var view: UIView?
    public var image: UIImage?

    public init(view: UIView?, image: UIImage?) {
        super.init()
        self.view = view
        self.image = image
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Here is the code of adding a 3D model into the screen.

```
let idleScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/idleFixed.dae")!
//        let idleScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/piper_pa18.dae")!

        // This node will be parent of all the animation models
        let node1 = SCNNode()

        // Add all the child nodes to the parent node
        for child in idleScene.rootNode.childNodes {
            node1.addChildNode(child)
        }
```

If I add below line then a 3D model will add into the app but not into a specific coordinate.

```
sceneLocationView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node1)
```

But I want to add a 3D object. Can anyone help me how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried `node1.position = yourPosition` after your `for` loop? and `yourPosition` will be type of `SCNVector3`

Comment: Yes, I have added position  node1.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, 3)
                node1.scale = SCNVector3(0.2, 0.2, 0.2) But this will add only one 3D model in screen.

Comment: then you need to add `idleScene.rootNode.addChildNode(node1)`

Comment: Actually, I have already fill node with idleScene's childs.

Comment: First you need to convert coordinates into scnvector.